# Is this an error in Humphreys' Lie algebra book? $\pi(T_m - T_{m-1}) = U_m - U_{m-1}$

Tags: lie-algebras, solution-verification

**Notations**

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra, $\mathfrak{T}(L)=\oplus_{i=0}^{\infty} T^i L$ the tensor algebra on $L$, and $\mathfrak{U}(L) = \mathfrak{T}(L)/J$ a universal enveloping algebra of $L$ where $J$ is the two sided ideal in $\mathfrak{T}(L)$ generated by all $x \otimes y - y \otimes x - [x, y]$ ($x, y \in L$). Denote the canonical homomorphism $\mathfrak{T}(L) \rightarrow \mathfrak{U}(L)$ by $\pi$. For brevity, write $\mathfrak{T} = \mathfrak{T}(L)$, $\mathfrak{U} = \mathfrak{U}(L)$, and $T^m = T^m(L)=\underbrace{L \otimes L \otimes \cdots \otimes L}_{m \text{ times}}$.

**Question and My Thoughts**

I'm reading on *Introduction to Lie algebras and Representation Theory* (3rd edition, p.91) written by J.Humphreys. In the preliminary stage of the formulating the PBW theorem, he define a filtration on $\mathfrak{T}$ by $T_m = T^0 \oplus T^1 \oplus \cdots \oplus T^m $ and set $U_m = \pi(T_m)$, with the following claim.

> Since $\pi$ maps $T^m$  into $U_m$, the composite linear map $\phi_m \colon T^m \rightarrow U_m \rightarrow U_m / U_{m-1}$ makes  sense. **It is surjective, because** $\pi(T_m - T_{m-1}) = U_m - U_{m-1}$.

However, I think $\pi(T_m - T_{m-1}) \neq U_m - U_{m-1}$ in general. For example, let $x$ and $y$ be linearly independent elements of $L$. Then $x \otimes y - y \otimes x \in T_2 - T_1$, but $\pi(x \otimes y - y \otimes x) = \pi([x, y]) \in U_1 = \pi(T_1)$. Of course, it is straightforward to show $\pi(T_m - T_{m-1}) \supset U_m - U_{m-1}$ so the surjectivity of $\phi_m$ follows.

Is there any fault in my reasoning?